# Cтилистика

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Подскажите, корректно ли употребление слова «заранее» в предложении «Она должна быть рассчитана на заранее неопределенное количество фактов»?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, правильно. Хотя тут от смысла зависит. Вам бы надо всё-таки контекст привести чуть поподробнее.
Если речь идёт о том, что число фактов устанавливается только в процессе использования "её", то безусловно только "заранее" — в значении предварительно, прежде и т.д. Тут даже "априори" будет не совсем точным. Но только не "заведомо", как тут предлагают. Абсолютно не тот смысл, да и крепко отдаёт то ли просторечием, то ли вообще негативом...

**...

VOCAB: заведомый

STYLGL: (о чем-нибудь отрицательном)

DEF: хорошо известный, несомненный

LEGLEXAM: З. обманщик. Заведомая ложь. Заведомо (нареч.). неверные сведения.**
© Ожегов (на старлинге)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, тут, скорее, правильно будет "на ЗАВЕДОМО неопределенное количество фактов". Если, конечно, я правильно поняла смысл предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с предыдущим комментарием.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, можно использовать слово *заранее*, только в таком случае *не* с причастием будет писаться раздельно, а смысл предварительной неопределенности сохранится: "Она должна быть рассчитана на заранее не определенное количество фактов".

Comment: Мне понятна ваша логика, согласился бы с вами на все сто, не прослеживайся здесь очевидный для меня математический или программистский контекст. Там понятие неопределенный, неопределённость далеко от прямого отрицания определённости, скорее уж наоборот. Определённый (по определению) - тот, который не является неопределённым.
Нечто аналогичное имеет место в милицейском сленге. "Следствием неустатовленное лицо" - устоявшийся оборот. Хотя с точки зрения простого смертного должно бы быть "не установленное".